# lualatex file luabidi.sty not found. where must I place it?

Tags: latex, hebrew, lyx

I am getting lyx set up on my xubonto laptop. I have used some online guides to set the thing and slowly worked my way around several issues, so I cannot recall exactly what I have set up. I am using non-Tex "Culmus" fonts (had to rename them for luatex to recognize them), and Document Class article standard.
Lyx have no problem exporting a luaTex file (or a xetex file) but am complaining about a luabidi.sty file-not-found (or a bidi.sty file-not-found).

So I have downloaded luabidi but I am not sure where to place it..
it contains 2 folders tex and doc, so I have placed their content in

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luabidi
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/luatex/luabidi

But it did not resolve the issue... Some specific help would be appreciated, as well as may be a better way to manage luatex packages and files?

Answer (score 3):

Installing texlive-lang-arabic fixed it.